# syslog-ng complaining about plugin 'tfjson'

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04, syslog-ng

I keep getting this error from cron every night. I can't figure out what syslog-ng is looking for. I've installed `syslog-ng-mod-json` module through apt, however the problem persists whenever syslog-ng is restarted. Anyone know the fix for this?

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/usr/lib/syslog-ng/3.5.3', module='tfjson'
```

Comment: Hi, logrotate sends a HUP signal to syslog-ng, and causes it to reload its configuration. This is normal. The problem is that syslog-ng cannot find the json module for some reason. Check the available modules (execute the syslog-ng --version command), and find which is json-related, then include the following line in your syslog-ng config:


@module <modulename>

I kinda remember that the tfson module was renamed to json-plugin, but I'm not sure in which version.

Comment: Thanks. I found the borked module reference in `vi /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/00load-tfjson.conf`. Changed it to `@module json-plugin` and all is well.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked!

Comment: if you re-post as an answer, I'll accept it. This has been driving me batty for a couple months. You should get the SF bling for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logrotate sends a HUP signal to syslog-ng, and causes it to reload its configuration. This is normal. The problem is that syslog-ng cannot find the json module for some reason. Check the available modules (execute the syslog-ng --version command), and find which is json-related, then include the following line in your syslog-ng config: @module  I kinda remember that the tfson module was renamed to json-plugin, but I'm not sure in which version.